# ng-bootstrap: ngb-progressbar custom background color

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to set the progress color and the examples I see online don't work.

I have an Angular (v4) component using the ng-bootstrap's ngb-progressbar component (with Bootstrap 4).

```
<ngb-progressbar type="primary" [value]="progress">
    <span>{{ progress }} %</span>
</ngb-progressbar>
```

How do I style the background color of this component's progress that will work in Chrome, IE and FF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just by overriding the class `.progress-bar` and placing an `!important` against the css

```
.progress-bar{

background-color:black !important;  

}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TrIe1wBOUtYtPj9NJRdD?p=info)**

Comment: Thank-you, that works with a global style sheet, but how would I apply that at the component level? :host /deep/ progress ....?

Comment: yup you are right,  :host /deep/ .progress-bar {black} worked, thank-you

Comment: actually let me know if you prefer I start another question but I cannot seem to set background color for just one instance of a progress? The above sets all of them, when I apply a custom css class to the ngb-progressbar it ignores it..

Answer (score 4):

Try this insert in your css styles

```css
::ng-deep .progress-bar {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if you are doing this in a scoped component. In this way, the ngb-progressbar can't read your style